# Pipe output of "at" delayed command to a file

Tags: bash, at

I want to append to a file in a few minutes' time.

I naively thought I could do:

```bsh
echo "hello world" >> /tmp/foo.txt | at NOW + 1 MINUTE
```

But that appends to the file immediately.

I tried:

```bsh
echo "hello world" | at NOW + 1 MINUTE >> /tmp/foo.txt
```

But that doesn't write any output at all.

I know I can do:

```bsh
$ at NOW + 1 MINUTE
warning: commands will be executed using /bin/sh
at> echo "HElllo world" >> /tmp/foo.txt
at>
at> <EOT>
job 11 at Wed Feb 17 17:58:00 2021
```

but this feels like "cheating".

How can I express what I want without using a heredoc?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting the STDOUT of a successful `at` command is not what you want.

To create an "at" job that does "`echo "Hello, world"`", you'll use the backslash (`\`), which makes the following character differently special (if character is special, treat it as not special or if character is not special treat it as special).

To get `at` to perform

```
echo "Hello, world"
```

you must send that command to `at`.

```
echo "echo \"Hello  world\"" | at ...
```

Another way is to use both forms of quoting:

```
echo 'echo "Hello, world"' | at ...
```